# create and run bash script on start of runlevel5

Tags: bash, centos, runlevel

I have created a following hello bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello Run Level 5"
```

I put this script in the /etc/rc.d/rc5.d directory with a name S100RunLevel5. How can I make this script to run terminal and show text, once I login to GUI?

Comment: What GUI? You mean X? Logging of user in, has nothing to do with boot process and changing runlevels. Boot scripts always output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to cache some sort of "post-start" command to your x-server before it gets initialized.  Though, Run Level 5 might be the start of your GUI in your OS.  For giggles, try something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# the extra bash command is to keep the window open
xterm -e 'echo "Hello Run Level 5"; bash'
```